# Facebook oauth dialog redirect after login problem on mobile touch site

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-authentication

We redirect users to below URL on mobile phones for application authorisation:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://www.server.com/callback.php&scope=offline_access,user_likes,publish_stream,publish_checkins,user_checkins&display=wap

If the user is logged in to Facebook on his/her phone, no problem, Facebook automatically redirects to oauth dialog page.

If user is not logged in, Facebook asks them to login first.
On wap site(A Nokia phone), it redirects to oauth dialog without any problem after login.
But on touch site(An iPhone), it add hastags to URL, redirects user to his/her Facebook homepage.

Even display=wap parameter on URL doesn't help on this issue.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Is the `access_token` in the URL fragment (hash)? If so that sounds like you have somehow invoked Client-side Flow of oAuth 2.0. You can read about that here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: No, it redirects not to callback URL but http://m.facebook.com/home.php?__user=10000215445XXX

Comment: Ive had that behavior in the past when a sanbdoxed application is authenticating a non-approved developer. Otherwise, have you tried using the `display=touch` for the iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here's a cleaner solution. (I hadn't seen the API for getLoginUrl at the time of my previous post. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl)

```
require_once("facebook.php");

$config = array(
    "appId" => APP_ID,
    "secret" => APP_SECRET
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
    "scope" => "offline_access,user_likes,publish_stream,publish_checkins,user_checkins",
    "redirect_uri" => "http://www.server.com/callback.php",
    "display" => "touch"
);

$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);

header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem and had troubles isolating it since it worked in Chrome on the desktop but not while using the iPhone's Safari browser.

I did a urlencode around the redirect_url parameter and set display to touch. So to use your link above as an example, I'd try this:

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.server.com%2Fcallback.php&scope=offline_access,user_likes,publish_stream,publish_checkins,user_checkins&display=touch

I sincerely hope that works for you. It seemed to have brought me luck.