# facebook mobile share dialog not appearing after login

Tags: facebook, mobile, dialog

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to send users to the mobile share dialog based on some input they provide. This works fine on desktop browsers and on the Android browsers I've tried.  However, it fails on an iPhone 3G if the user is not already logged in. The user is prompted to log in, but after logging in they're faced with an empty screen on Facebook - basically a dead end.

Here is the URL I try to send them to (edits made to hide client info):

http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=123456789012345&display=touch&link=http%3a%2f%2fwww.someotherdomain.com%2fdir%2fsubdir%2f12345&picture=http%3a%2f%2fwww.someotherdomain.com%2fImages%2fdir%2fsubdir%2f12345678.jpg&name=Some+Name&caption=Some+Caption+-+Its+Location&description=Title%20Of%20Event%2c+now+playing+at+Some+Location.&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fsomedomain.com%3a54251%2fcheckin%2fthanks%2ffacebook%2fsuccess%2f

Here is the URL on the login screen as it appears on the iPhone:

http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=123456789012345&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Fsomedomain.com%2Fcheckin%2Fthanks%2Ffacebook%2Fsuccess%2F&next=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Ffeed%3F_path%3Dfeed%26app_id%3D123456789123456%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fsomedomain.com%252Fcheckin%252Fthanks%252Ffacebook%252Fsuccess%252F%26display%3Dtouch%26link%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.someotherdomain.com%252Fdir%252Fsubdir%252F12345%26picture%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.someotherdomain.com%252FImages%252Fdir%252Fsubdir%252F12345678.jpg%26name%3DSome%2BName%26caption%3DSome%2BCaption%2B-%2BIts%2BLocation%26description%3DTitle%2BOf%2BEvent%252C%2Bnow%2Bplaying%2Bat%2BSome%2BLocation.%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1&_rdr

Am I missing anything? Perhaps I didn't encode the URLs in the parameters correctly?   [This question sounds similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566970/facebook-oauth-dialog-redirect-after-login-problem-on-mobile-touch-site), but that is focused on authorizing an application and I don't want that--I just want the user to share something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me if I forwarded to www.facebook.com instead of m.facebook.com.  That's consistent with the facebook docs, but prior to this I had been having issues with mobile browsers getting non-mobile pages unless I specifically pointed to m.facebook.com...Seems they cleared that part of it up.